# Can I specify tags as a property to avoid cluttering the headline?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Having tags in the headline clutters the view and is quite distracting when the tags are not directly pertinent to it. An example of this is the `noexport` tag which describes what to do with the headline and not what the headline is about.

Is it possible to move such tags to the property drawer so that they're not as visible? I tried [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16822/how-can-i-use-the-properties-drawer-with-a-tags-property-and-asign-multiple-valu) solution hoping that since I wanted to move just one tag, I wouldn't face the same issue as the OP did in that question but it doesn't work and exporting the org file resulted in a headline with the `noexport` tag specified as a property getting exported as well

This is what I tried:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:TAGS: noexport
:END:
```

Comment: No, you cannot. TAGS and planning info in particular (SCHEDULED, DEADLINE) have to be at the end of the headline and just after the headline (resp.) That's part of the syntax.